# Show the decreasing of a recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_1 = \frac{1}{4}$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}{x_n+1}$. It seems that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 2}$ is decreasing based on a program, but I'm unsure how to prove it.
We have $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{1}{(x_n +1)x_n^{\frac{1}{n}}}$, but it's not obvious how to demonstrate that $(x_n +1)x_n^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq 1$ for all $n\geq 2$.

**My attempt:**

By induction we can prove that $\,\forall n\geqslant2\,,\;0<x_n<1\;.$
Let $\,f_n(x)=(1+x)^nx\,.$
$f’_n(x)>0\;\;\forall n\geqslant2\,,\,\forall x\in]0,1[\,.$
How could I continue ?

Comment: What have you tried ? please show your effort without using programing.

Comment: Yes, that's what you should post.

Comment: Numerically it looks like $x_n$ decays like $\frac1n\log n$ times a constant.

Comment: Thank you for this remark, but I'm not sure if there is a way to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the following three lemmas.

Proofs for the lemmas are written at the end of this answer.

**Lemma 1** : If $0\lt x\lt 1$ and $n\ge 2$, then $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\dfrac{x^{1-\frac 1n}}{x+1}\bigg)\gt 0$.

**Lemma 2** : If $0\lt x\lt 1$ and $n\ge 2$, then $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}\bigg(\dfrac{x^{1-\frac 1n}}{x+1}\bigg)\lt 0$.

**Lemma 3** : $0\lt x_n\lt 1$.

---

Using the lemmas, let us show by induction on $n$ that for $n\ge 3$, $$x_{n}\lt x_{n-1}\tag1$$

For $n=3$, $(1)$ holds since
$$x_{3}=\frac{2}{9}\sqrt 5=\frac{10\sqrt 5}{45}\lt \frac{36}{45}=\frac 45=x_2$$

Suppose that $(1)$ holds for $n$.

Then, using the lemmas, we have
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}{x_{n}+1}\lt \frac{x_{n-1}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}{x_{n-1}+1}\lt\frac{x_{n-1}^{1-\frac 1{n-1}}}{x_{n-1}+1}=x_{n}.\ \blacksquare$$

---

In the following, let us show the three lemmas :

**Lemma 1** : If $0\lt x\lt 1$ and $n\ge 2$, then $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\dfrac{x^{1-\frac 1n}}{x+1}\bigg)\gt 0$.

*Proof* :

We have
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\dfrac{x^{1-\frac 1n}}{x+1}\bigg)=\frac{(n-1)-x}{nx^{\frac 1n}(x+1)^2}\gt 0.\ \ \blacksquare$$

---

**Lemma 2** : If $0\lt x\lt 1$ and $n\ge 2$, then $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}\bigg(\dfrac{x^{1-\frac 1n}}{x+1}\bigg)\lt 0$.

*Proof* :

We have
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}\bigg(\dfrac{x^{1-\frac 1n}}{x+1}\bigg)=\frac{x^{1-\frac 1n}\ln x}{n^2(x+1)}\lt 0.\ \ \blacksquare$$

---

**Lemma 3** : $0\lt x_n\lt 1$.

*Proof* :

Let us show by induction on $n$.

We have $0\lt x_1=\frac 14\lt 1$ and $0\lt x_2=\frac 45\lt 1$.

Suppose that $0\lt x_n\lt 1$. Then, it follows from lemma 1 that $$0\lt x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^{1-\frac 1n}}{x_n+1}\lt \frac{1^{1-\frac 1n}}{1+1}=\frac 12\lt 1.\ \ \blacksquare$$

Comment: Thank you, despite its simplicity, it went unnoticed by me.